# Power BI calculate increase based on next & previous values

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm new to Power BI and have an assignment to hand in for school. Awaiting for 365 admin to grant access to power BI community I'm hoping someone can help me explain the following:

In this basic [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzSTN.png) called Population, there is data over 10 years for each country and their population.
I would like to add a column and with DAX formula calculate the increase relative to last year.

So I would think the basic idea is something like

```
Increase = CALCULATE(SUMX(population, Filter(Population, Population[Year] = Population[year] + 1) - Population[Population))
```

But I'm not finding the right formula.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calculated_column:

1. `NewColumn_calculate = population[Population]-CALCULATE(SUM(population[Population]), FILTER(population, EARLIER(population[Country]) = population[Country] && EARLIER(population[Year]) = population[Year] + 1))`
2. `NewColumn_sumx = population[Population]-SUMX(FILTER(population, EARLIER(population[Country]) = population[Country] && EARLIER(population[Year]) = population[Year] + 1), population[Population])`

measure:

`Measure = SUM(population[Population]) - SUMX(FILTER(all(population), population[Country] = MAX(population[Country]) && population[Year] = MAX(population[Year]) - 1), population[Population])`

Comment: Thank you J.P for the 3 different options! All giving the right result.

Comment: Although I have to admit the +1 to get a previous row in EARLIER(population[Year]) = population[Year] + 1) is confusing me :)